# How to display Custom metabox value in front-side?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

```js
if (!function_exists('save_detail')) {
  function save_detail($post_id) {
    if (isset($_POST['txtname']) && !empty($_POST['txtname'])) {
      $textValue = $_POST['txtname'];
      update_post_meta($post_id, "txtname", $textValue);
    }
  }
  add_action("save_post", "save_detail");
}
```

Comment: You are saving the custom meta in this code. Show us the code, you are using to display it.

Comment: It will be shown automatically after added action. maybe you want a custom style, for that check this option: https://github.com/farinspace/wpalchemy